# How to distinguish devices connected to chromecast

Tags: javascript, chromecast

How do I distinguish devices connected to the chromecast in my custom receiver.

Should I do it with `window.castReceiverManager.getSenders()`

Answer (score 0):

If by "distinguish" you mean getting a list of connected senders, then you need to [call](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager#getSenders) `cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager#getSenders()`

Comment: I want to edit/add values to a specific connected device, I know i can use getSender(senderId) to get an user but I'm not sure if I should save data there and how I can get the senderId every time.

Comment: Every sender has a unique ID and as long as it is connected, ID is preserved.  Beyond that, it is your own receiver logic that decides what to do.

Comment: thank you for the clarification, so the Unique ID is the same as this `4:client-56006`, I get this when i ask for the senders, do you know what the `4: ` means in front of the client-****